# Laravel redirect back post with input and errors AND render

Tags: laravel-4

I have a AJAX application I'm working on with Laravel 4.

I post forms by binding to the forms, serializing and returning. The response from the server is in JSON so more variables can be given.

For normal pages I simply return

```
View::make('something')->render();
```

But when posting and returning with errors the system fails for me. I would love to do something like

```
Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation->messages())->render();
```

This fails, which I can understand.

So I tried

```
View::make('something')->withInput()->withErrors($validation->messages())->render();
```

This too fails seeing the `View::make` does not have a function `withInput`.

So to get around this all I made it work with

```
{{ Form::input('email', 'email', (isset($input['email'])) ? e($input['email']) : null, array('class' => 'form-control validation', 'placeholder' => Lang::get('global.placeholder.email'))); }}
```

But I don't want to do the if statement for the value seeing it's ugly ($errors accepted even when empty in rendering by default).

So the question is: Is there a way to render a view/redirect with inputs.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem when doing multistep forms and ended up doing the same thing you mention above. Instead of `withInput()`, I used `with('input', Input::all())`. I would be interested to see if anyone else came up with an alternative approach.

Comment: I believe the `withInput()` method when used with `Redirect` sets a session value called `_old_input` as the output of `Input:all(). This session value is then read by `Input::old('key')` when the page is loaded. So knowing this, doing as @Jeemusu says is the way that I would go.

Comment: @carbontwelve Just gave this a test and it works great! Thanks! You should make that an answer.

Comment: Well thank you :) But I would like it shorter. The "if" statement is bugging me. I hate doing them in my view. That being said, I might just move the statements to a model with a checker. Seems more clean. I'll probably make that the answer than to make it fit the coding standards better and thus the view cleaner. Cause I think we'll probably have to wait for Laravel 5 to find an out of the box solution

Comment: @Matt ah, yes. You could then in that case in your model have a method that returns an `$input` array pre-filled with the defaults for inputs in its form and have the logic there for merging old input. I would suggest looking at how laravel.io works, they use Form Model classes like so: https://github.com/LaravelIO/laravel.io/blob/master/app/Lio/Articles/ArticleForm.php to store form based logic.

Answer (score 0):

Like stated before, it's going to be a model:

```
Class DefaultValues {

    // set default values or define inputs
    public static $oInputs as array(
        'email' => '',
        'password' => '',
    );

    public function catchEmpty() {
        if(Request::is_post()) {
            foreach(self::$oInputs as $sInputKey => $sValue) {
                Input::post($sInputKey) = (isset(Input::post($sInputKey)) ? Input::post($sInputKey) : $sValue;
            }
        }
        if(Request::is_get()) {
            foreach(self::$oInputs as $sInputKey => $sValue) {
                Input::get($sInputKey) = (isset(Input::get($sInputKey)) ? Input::get($sInputKey) : $sValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this you can keep your blades like they were. No altering to $input. Seemed better to me because I'm lazy.

Just use:

```
View::make('something')->render();
```

`Input::[something]([something]);` will be available without error. But you still have to set it unfortunately.

Please comment where needed.